# JSX One root element concept is confusing

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, create-react-app

As we are familiar with React JSX one root element concept. that there should be only one parent tag.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
         <h2>Start editing me</h2>
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
// this works
```

and if we do this it gives error

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1> A </h1>
      <h1> B </h1>
    );
  }
}
// this fails
```

But i tried something different but similar and it worked. I return array of jsx and somehow it worked. i could not understand why ?. If anyone can help me to understand. Any help will be appreciated.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ([<h4> bcd </h4>, <h4> abc </h4>])
  }
}

// this works.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a feature of [React since 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html), quoting:

> You can now return an array of elements from a component’s render method.

Devs have been ranting about wrapping nodes [for a while](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127), hence this feature.

As mentioned in the docs, don't forget to add keys though.

Comment: what magical things they do when you just execute the last code snippet returning with array ?

Comment: do they automatically put a wrapper when they detect returning thing is an array ?